# when do we indicate the "+ or -" sign in uncertainty

Tags: quantum-chemistry

how can we know when to indicate "+ or -" sign in uncertainty calculations because I noticed some problems has been solved by this sign and some has not.

Comment: Can you give us examples of what you mean by `some problems have been solved by this sign and some have not`? As far as I am aware, if you have uncertainty and you know what it is, you indicate it.

Comment: To me uncertainty is + AND - anyway...

Comment: when calculating the uncertainty of more that one problem .. I noticed that some final answers involve the sign of + or -
to illustrate, when calculating uncertainty in position there is NO "+ or -" sign .. while in calculating uncertainty in momentum, there is.

Comment: it's just because when indicating uncertainty, it's implicite. So if there is no signs, it means +/- anyway.

Answer (score 6):

You either use both "+" and "-", $\pm$, or neither in which case it is implied that you mean $\pm$.

Usually uncertainty is expressed in a way that is symmetric about the mean, such as $123\pm4$, meaning to a certain degree of confidence the true value is between 119 and 127.

However, you could write $123^{+5}_{-3}$ to indicate the best estimate of the true value is 123 and to a certain degree of confidence the true value is between 120 and 128.

For example, if you were highly certain that an object is a cube, and measure its edge as 100 $\pm 20$, then it might be better to express the volume of the cube as

$1.0^{+0.7}_{-0.5} \times 10^6$